# Trying to find the full width at half maximum for a noisy signal

Tags: matlab, signals

I am currently looking to find the FWHM of a signal.
The peak of the signal is around 1.0 but the lowest value is only around 0.6. 
So, in fact, I don't have a half maximum value.

How could I proceed to analyze the curve in a similar fashion?

Here is an image of the curve:

[image: curve]

Comment: I assume you'd need to offset the signal to be centered at 0 before the FWHM calculation. However it seems that FWHM is a value generally computed for gaussians, and your data is very much not gaussian

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you assume an offset on the x-axis? the curve is already centered at x=0, this can be seen in the image of my signal, which i attached to my message. or did you mean something else?

Comment: I mean y-axis, the x-axis is what you are looking for. Also, it looks like its common to get the FWHM on non-Gaussian data, apologies.

Comment: Well as you said yourself you do not reach half of the peak value, so based on what you currently have you can only state that the FWHM >= 4.8 (Hz maybe). In order to capture the true FWHM of the signal you will have to have a higher sampling rate which will allow to see higher frequency component.

Comment: Since the signal doesn't go to zero, FWHM might be the wrong measure. We do not know if it is reasonable to rescale it as we do not know where it comes from physically. Since you asked for alternatives: equivalent width (find the width of a rectangle that has the same height [maximum] and the same area as your curve), 3dB energy width (find width that contains 50% [or any other quantile] of the total energy) are two examples. What makes sense phyiscally depends on where this signals comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that min and max of the signal `y` is 0.6 and 1 respectively you can find FWHM:

`idx1` and `idx2` each return indexes of two points before and after the desired point at half. We can use these points to interpolate value of `x` at the half of `y`.

```
%height at half
h=(0.6+1)/2;
idx1=find(y>h,1) +[-1 0];
idx2=find(y>h,1,'last') +[0 1];
x1 = interp1(y(idx1),x(idx1),h);
x2 = interp1(y(idx2),x(idx2),h);
w = x2 - x1;
```

[image: FWHM]